# sqlite, mono, C# cross platform

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, moma

I am using sqlite in my C# project. MoMA complains about the DLLs and i am unsure what to do on the mac/linux side. What are things i generally need to do when porting external DLLs?

Comment: What exactly is MoMA complaining about.  As far as I know SQLite is supported by using the Mono.Data.SqliteClient namespace.

Comment: @DaleRagan That old lib has been all but replaced by Mono.Data.Sqlite now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the SQLite assembly that's shipped with Mono - it's derived from the one you are probably using now.

See http://mono-project.com/SQLite for more details

Comment: makes it useless: 
If you do not have SQLite, download it. There are binaries for Windows and Linux. You can put the .dll or .so along side your application binaries, or in a system-wide library path.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at the C# reimplementation of [SQLite on googlecode](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/).  This started life as a [line-by-line port of the C++ SQLite](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Aug-06.html) but after lots of improvements now outperforms the original for many types of operation.

Comment: @acidzombie24 - the original was about 5x slower, typically.  The latest version is much faster than that as shown in the benchmarks at http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/wiki/Benchmarks

Comment: @Stewart: You do know that bigger values are worse? as its time and you want the shortest time. Interesting, it looks like some of these values are shorter then SQLite. Very interesting. It looks like most of these values are larger and SQLite is still the fastest on inserting. I wonder what stats i should look at for updates. But, both are pretty fast so it doesnt matter.

Comment: @acidzombie24 - LOL - I didn't say SQLite was faster overall.  I was originally just pointing out that for many (not all) operations it was faster. In my comment, I was merely pointing out that it was now better than "about 5x slower".

Comment: Also, don't bother using this if you want x64... it won't run on anything except x86.

Comment: "Any CPU" build is coming to support NHibernate 3.0 straight from the box. [link](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/issues/detail?id=77)

Comment: @Karl - it works fine with x64. You just need to be careful when choosing the target platform for the build.

Answer (score 1):

PHXSoftware's [System.Data.Sqlite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) runs on Mono.